# Jade / Expressjs: Pass objects from server to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to pass an object from my endpoint to Jade but It keeps giving me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on Stat! Can someone help me please. Here is my code:

```
app.get('/stats', function (req, res, next) {

    var stats ={
        'm0t20': {a:0,b:0,c:0,d:0},
        'm20t30': {a:0,b:0,c:0,d:0},
    };
   res.render('chart',{'stat':stats});
 }
```

and in my jade and I cant get the value of stat:

```
 script(type='text/javascript').
        var stats= #{stat};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to interpolate object from you express, the easiest and cleanest way is to serialize them.
For the moment, once interpolated, you are trying to write something like this:

```
var stats = [Object object];
```

Which isn't a valid JavaScript syntax :/
So, on the server side, serialize your object:

```
 app.get(..., function (req, res) {
    var stats = { ... };
    res.render('chart', { stats: JSON.stringify(stats) });
 });
```

And, on the client side, just use the serialized object; You'll need to use `!` instead of `#` to prevent jade from escaping characters like quotes.

```
script.
    var stats = !{stats};
    alert(stats.myProp);
```

**Keep in mind that you are injecting direct JavaScript code into your page.**
**DO NOT do that if the serialized object could contain any user input**